# App Store rejection due to Firebase phone auth

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, app-store, firebase-analytics

Our app uses Firebase phone auth. The App Store review has rejected the app due to pushes being required:

> Guideline 4.5.4 - Design - Apple Sites and Services
>
> We noticed that your app requires push notifications in order to function.
>
> Specifically, we noticed if the Push Notifications setting was not enabled on our device, we encountered an error message after entering our phone number within the app.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Push notifications must be optional and must obtain the user's consent to be used within the app.

And they've also attached the screenshot that depicts Firebase error "Remote notifications and background fetching need to be set up for the app [...]"

Firebase documentation states that APNs notifications are absolutely required for phone auth to function:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

> To use phone number authentication, your app must be able to receive APNs notifications from Firebase. When you sign in a user with their phone number for the first time on a device, Firebase Authentication sends a silent push notification to the device to verify that the phone number sign-in request comes from your app. (For this reason, phone number sign-in cannot be used on a simulator.)

However App Store review guidelines state that Push Notifications must not be required in order for the app to function: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

> 4.5.4 Push Notifications must not be required for the app to function, and should not be used for advertising, promotions, or direct marketing purposes or to send sensitive personal or confidential information.

Users need to sign in before they can use the app (the app is about sending digital GIF invitations to your guests and sharing photos), which is why Push Notifications are basically required for the app to function, if the sign in method is Firebase phone auth.

We have tested the app a lot, and the authentication works without a problem when push notifications are enabled (on real devices, both in distribution Ad Hoc builds with production environment and development builds with sandbox environment).

Come to think of it, how did App Review team even disable Push Notifications? The notification center setting does not stop actual pushes, it just doesn't display them.
[image: Setting is turned off]
We have tested with this setting off, and firebase phone auth works fine, pushes are still coming through as expected.

I am very surprised with this issue, as Firebase is a huge service provider. Did anyone else encounter this issue?
Are there plans to remove APNs requirement for phone auth? Is there maybe some other way to use Firebase phone auth without pushes?

Comment: It sounds like you need to provide an alternative authentication method other than firebase phone auth and explain to users about these options.

Comment: *firebaser here* I'm sorry to hear about this problem. That's clearly not the experience we'd like you to have. This is the first time I hear of this issue though. Can you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) so we can understand better how your app uses Phone number authentication and how that relates to the rejection?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi, I was also surprised that there are no other people with a rejection like this that I can find. I have written the support ticket on Friday, but I don't expect the answer before Monday. The app uses phone auth in a straightforward manner, you download the app, you watch/skip the tutorial, you have to sign in with phone number, and that is where App Review team that disabled Push Notifications on their iPad is unable to proceed. The rule they cite (about APNs having to be optional) does exist, so they are in the right it seems.

Comment: That's clearly a problem in firebase-ui implementation. it doesn't run well on some iPad devices.
I encountered this problem and also apple did. it caused 6 (!!!) rejections by apple and a major drawback in release time. and still not approved. almost sorry i choose Firebase phone authentication for my app.

Comment: Apple has now rejected my app for the 7th time claiming it cannot approve apps that can't work when Push notifications are optional: "Push notifications must be optional and must obtain the user's consent to be used within the app." And due to Firebase phone login behavior this is a real stopper. looking for a different approach now. Using Firebase login caused a delay of over 2 months (!!!!) in my app approval. this is unreasonable. avoid at all cost from using Firebase phone login in your iOS app till Google fix this problem.

Comment: Hi user3228240, if you're still blocked on this, can you please [contact support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) so we can help troubleshoot?

Comment: This is a HUGE Firebase flaw.  I am migrating from Digits to Firebase and this makes our app unusable for a large number of people (everyone who has already disabled push notifications).  I've contacted support and hope to hear back soon, but I'm not optimistic. The only solution is that they release a new SDK which does not require APNs being enabled.

Comment: @user3228240 Good news everybody, Firebase 4.2.0 has been released which fixes this bug

Comment: Having this same issue now. All was working, then this most recent version, rejection after rejection over not being able to get recaptcha working on app reviews devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPD: Firebase 4.2.0 has rolled out, which fixes the issue. You will need to add your reverse-client-id which looks something like this: `com.googleusercontent.apps.123456-abcdefg99` to URL schemes in your Info.plist, and you are set.

> To find this
>   value, open the GoogleService-Info.plist configuration file, and look for the
>   REVERSED_CLIENT_ID key.

---

Firebase support has confirmed this bug and has given the response to this issue:

> to me
>   Thank you for the detailed information Leet. This is indeed an odd situation, and our Phone Auth engineers are taking a look. I'll get back to you as soon as I have an answer.
>
> Best,
>   Jeff

---

> to me
>   Hi Leet,
>
> Our engineers are working internally on a long-term fix for this, but in the meantime, would like to meet with you to see if we can figure out a workaround.

It appears that there is indeed a bug in Firebase phone auth / Firebase UI.

Comment: Migrating back to Digits - a service which will be discontinued in a month is not a solution. I identified the root cause in my post, yet you accepted your own answer which gives no insight into the problem.

Answer (score 11):

Firebaser here. We have released an updated Firebase Auth SDK, 4.2.0, as Leetmory mentioned, which should hopefully resolve these issues going forward.

The issue was caused by the fact that the Firebase Auth SDK using APNs to validate the request - this is to minimize the risk of SMS spam abuse or similar. The validation uses a silent APNs notification, so doesn't require explicit user consent for iOS 8 and above. However, this still failed if APNs was completely disabled, as in this review case.

The 4.2.0 release introduced the facility to use a reCAPTCHA prompt inside an SFSafariViewController (or webview for older iOS) to prevent abuse if APNs isn't available. We don't expect this to happen very much, but it accounts for the unusual state encountered here. It also enables support for testing Firebase Phone Auth on the simulator!

You'll notice there is a new `uiDelegate` parameter on the `verifyPhoneNumber` method. In most cases you wont need to use this, but it is part of the fallback verification.

What you will need to do, if you haven't already, is add the `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` (from the `GoogleService-Info.plist`) as a custom URL scheme. This will allow the reCAPTCHA view to return validation to your app.

There is a gotchas to be aware of in the current version though:

1. In the callback from `verifyPhoneNumber` you'll need to redispatch to the main thread, using `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` - this will be fixed in the next version of Firebase Auth!

Other than that, things should work as normal! We definitely recommend supporting silent push where ever possible to ensure the best user experience.

For a full walk through, see the full Phone Auth [developer guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth).

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Firebase support and here's an excerpt:

> In terms of the concern around users disabling push notifications - Disabling push notification for the app by the user does not normally prevent users from signing in using their phone number with Firebase Auth. Our requirement is that the app must set up and enable push notification, not the user. Regardless of if the user accepts or declines your app's push notification prompt phone auth will continue to work since we use silent pushes that don't require any action from the user.

I researched further and found that silent push notifications do indeed arrive to the device even when the user explicitly disables push notifications.  To disable silent push notifications you would need to go to Settings -> Your App -> Background Refresh to disable it.  See [Is Silent Remote Notifications possible if user has disabled push for the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644343/is-silent-remote-notifications-possible-if-user-has-disabled-push-for-the-app)

So you can tell the App Store Review team that your login will only work when Background Refresh is enabled. I don't believe this violates their terms.

**EDIT**

After some testing, it appears that phone auth can work when Background Refresh is disabled. However, it works for me because Firebase already has access to my APNS device token.  I have found no way to disassociate my device token from Firebase - they provide no API for it.  This unfortunately makes it impossible to test the scenario where a new user disables Background Refresh and Remote Notifications before doing the phone auth which I believe may be the cause of the error.

**EDIT 2**

I can confirm that on a fresh device with a fresh install of our app, if you disable Background Refresh then Firebase Phone Auth will not work.  Once you enable it, it will work again.

The reason is that the SDK likely calls `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications]` which is ignored by the system if a user manually disables the Background Refresh and Notifications settings.

Unfortunately there is no workaround until Firebase releases a new SDK which does not require APNs.

Comment: Please read this part of the original question:  
"The notification center setting does not stop actual pushes, it just doesn't display them.  
We have tested with this setting off, and firebase phone auth works fine, pushes are still coming through as expected."  
  
The bug is in the Firebase UI, firebase support has confirmed it and are working on the fix.

Comment: You asked "how did App Review team even disable Push Notifications?" I'm telling you that they disabled Background Refresh which prevents silent push notifications from arriving.

Comment: When you say Push Notifications you should clarify whether you mean User Notificaitons or Remote Notifications.

Comment: "When you say Push Notifications you should clarify whether you mean User Notificaitons or Remote Notifications." - unfortunately App Review team did not specify what they meant. The quote from their message is as follows: "Specifically, we noticed if the Push Notifications setting was not enabled on our device, we encountered an error message after entering our phone number within the app." I can not clarify for them.

Comment: "I'm telling you that they disabled Background Refresh" - unfortunately this is not the case, as background refresh does not prevent pushes from arriving when the app is in the foreground, which is exactly when they encounter Firebase UI error message. You can read the response Firebase team has given us regarding this issue. They acknowlege this is the bug, and are fixing it.

Comment: I've edited my answer based on my findings that phone auth works when they already have your device token.  Have you found a way to test as though it is a fresh install on a fresh device where Firebase does not have the APNs device token already?  My suspicion is that if you disable Background Refresh and Notifications before the very first sign-in, it may cause the error.

Comment: After testing with a fresh install of a test app - you appear to be correct about the background-refresh setting! Thanks for taking your time to investigate this, it was a piece of valuable information for me.

Comment: A bit off-topic: if I use Firebase Phone Auth - the user will see APNS Permissions alert at the first app start, because Firebase SDK triggers it, right? I can't do anything to show this alert later in navigation hierarchy?

Comment: @OleksiiNezhyborets No there is no prompt because Firebase does not register for User Notifications, only for Remote notifications.