# Is permission always a must for sending notifications in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am coming from Android to IOS and need to implement push notifications. I am using AWS Pinpoint, which uses APNs, and so far everything is working. However, I see that user is asked if he wants to permit notifications or not...

Is there some way to send push notification (**perhaps without displaying it, but just delivering JSON data within app**) without asking permission?

Comment: it's strange how this isn't a permission in android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Silent Remote Notifications possible if user has disabled push for the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644343/is-silent-remote-notifications-possible-if-user-has-disabled-push-for-the-app)

Comment: @dan I would still need to ask for permissions, yes?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way to send push notification (perhaps without displaying it, but just delivering JSON data within app) without asking permission?

No there isn't , there should be an alert to allow sending notifications whatever it's configured with notification/data , for no sound/alert set this remove options

```
let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
```

Note also set

```
content-type = 1
```

in payload