# Usage (best/good practice) patterns for Silent Notification (in iOS and Android) and it usages for significant events

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, silent-notification

There are a number of questions that I noticed in this space and it gives me a good idea
of the notification space.

I found [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644343/is-silent-remote-notifications-possible-if-user-has-disabled-push-for-the-app) informative and want to thank the folks for the discussion in that thread.

However there are still a few questions that are unanswered in my head.

(1) What exactly is a silent notification?

My understanding is notifications that contain this flag value equals 1  "`content-available`" : 1

In the Apple ecosystem (APNS) this would be realized with this attribute
apns-push-type: background

(2) Can silent Notifications be turned-off?
I read that it can't be turned off however at the same breath I see that if "Remote Notifications" are turned off in iOS, then they would not be received.

(3) Is it a good practice to send key events/notifcations as a silent notification (e.g Multi-factor authentication) or should they rely on regular push notifications?

From what i have read and observed:

1. Silent Notifications are low priority ones
2. They are not guaranteed Delivery

My conclusion (based on my search and reading) is silent-notificaiton should not be used for critical events.

I was hoping a best practice article/blog in this space from all the players (Apple, Google etc)however i see info in bits and pieces.

Happy to put one together an article/blog as a give back when I have all the info at hand as i work through these questions.

Appreciate inputs, links and advice.

References:
[Pushing Background Updates to Your App]
[2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app?language=objc)

[Sending Notification Requests to APNs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns)

[Silent notifications works only when app in foreground](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126540)

Comment: No notifications are guaranteed delivery.  One big issue is that if your app is terminated then it will not be launched to receive the silent notification. A regular notification's payload is displayed by iOS and if the user taps it then your app is launched.  Remote notifications can't be turned off, but if you use a standard notification and the user has disabled the notification display, it is *like* they are turned off.  Silent notifications will still be delivered to your app if it is not terminated.  Low power mode may affect the delivery of silent notifications

Comment: Silent notifications can be throttled though, so there deliver is "less guaranteed". A common use case for silent notifications was to use the payload to present a local notification.  This is better achieved with a [notification extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension)