# When can users receive background notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios-background-mode

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/39373669/19557159, background push notification will not be delivered if both push notifications and background app refresh are turned off. But from my testing, I am still able to receive and process background notifications when the user turned both off. Is this expected?