# Are silent notifications received with background notifications turned off, while application is running in iOS?

Tags: ios, push-notification, silent-notification

I just took a look at [Is Silent Remote Notifications possible if user has disabled push for the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644343/is-silent-remote-notifications-possible-if-user-has-disabled-push-for-the-app).

It basically says the Silent Notifications disregard notification settings for user. It then says:

> Users still have the ability to switch off your app’s ability to
>   process a “silent push” by means of the “Background App Refresh”
>   control. Even though Apple Push Notification service (APNs) will
>   deliver a push marked “content-available” to your phone, the OS will
>   not wake up your app to receive it, effectively dropping it on the
>   floor.

This is confusing to me. I want to make silent notifications go out only while the app is open, to update state of the app while in use only. So I wouldn't care if background app refresh is off because I wouldn't need to "wake up [my] app to receive it".

Secondarily [Silent push notifications only delivered if device is charging and/or app is foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959472/silent-push-notifications-only-delivered-if-device-is-charging-and-or-app-is-for) talks about needing to have your phone plugged in to receive these notifications.

Both questions are from iOS 8, which is quite a ways back. Do they hold up all this time?

Answer (score 0):

My answers are based on observation and my work on the apple notification.
Before iOS 13

- Silent notification is not received even if notification is force killed by the user even if the `background app refresh is on`. Silent push received in case of foreground, background or killed by iOS

After iOS 13

- Silent notification are received always if `background app refresh is on`.But if `background app refresh is off` silent push received only in foreground and background case.

If you want to only send silent push in foreground or background you should not add `background mode` in capability in Xcode. So it will receive only when the application is in the foreground or background

Comment: I'm a little confuse what do you mean by `background app refresh`? Would that be the 
```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
 <array>
  <string>fetch</string>
```
fetch mode? on the `UIBackgroundModes ` ?